# How can I use transactions with fulltext indexing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, transactions, full-text-search

I'm using MySQL 5. Transactions are of paramount importance, but so is fulltext indexing. This seems to be a catch 22:

1. InnoDB supports transactions but not fulltext indexing.
2. MyISAM supports fulltext indexing but not transactions.

What techniques do developers employ to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use Sphinx or Solr/Lucene to provide full text indexing. Not exactly a pure mysql solution, but both are much faster than MySQL with full text searching.